# Unable to recover admin account ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, users

i had accidentally deleted the admin account. i am using the system from standard how to recover the administrator account which i had deleted, please do favour me in resolving this isssue.

Comment: Please tell us what you have done exactly. You can't delete the root account.

Answer (score 0):

Ceate a new account with `useradd <user>`. After creating an account with useradd, you have to create a password for the user with
`passwd <user>`. Then type the Password twice.

If you use `adduser <user>` ist will ask you for a password while creating the user.

Take a look at the help (adduser --help) for more options.